# Анимация выходит за пределы Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть анимация, которая возвращает Ellipse на начальную точку или же на конечную.
Все бы работало отлично, но есть одно: Когда я отпуская елипс - отсчитывает пиксели от той точки от которой отпустили мышку(и выходит за переделы Canvas). Как можно это изменить?

bool Action = false;

```
    double   InitPxls = 15;
    double FinitePxls = 420;
    double CenterPxls = 210;
    double Movement;
    Point Point;

private void CircleKnob_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Action = false;
            Mouse.Capture(null);

            ThicknessAnimation Knob = new ThicknessAnimation(); 
            ThicknessAnimation Shadow = new ThicknessAnimation(); 

            if (Movement < CenterPxls)
            {
                Knob.To   = CircleKnob.  Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                Shadow.To = CircleShadow.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                Knob.Duration   = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3); 
                Shadow.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3); 
                CircleKnob.  BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, Knob); 
                CircleShadow.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, Shadow); 
            }
            else
            {
                Knob.To   = CircleKnob.  Margin = new Thickness(190, 0, 0, 0); 
                Shadow.To = CircleShadow.Margin = new Thickness(190, 0, 0, 0); 
                Knob.Duration   = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3); 
                Shadow.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3); 
                CircleKnob.  BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, Knob); 
                CircleShadow.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, Shadow); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Все верно, Вы анимируете поле Margin а надо Canvas.SetLeft() указанного обьекта